# Редирект JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
var lang = ['ru','en','pl','hu','de','sv','pt','no','tr','fi','be'];

var link = window.location.href;

for (var i = 0; i < lang.length; i++){
    lang[i] = '/' + lang[i] + '/';
    if (link.indexOf(lang[i]) > -1 ) {
        document.write(lang[i]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Скажите пожалуйста,есть массив lang где хранится список языков.Есть url который помещён в переменную link.Как сделать так чтобы когда в url,аббревиатура языка не совпадала ни с одним из элементов массива,страница редиректилась на английскую версию.
К примеру landing.dev/de/ так и остаётся.А если меняем url на landing.dev/dima/ к примеру, то должен быть редирект на англ.версию,то есть на landing.dev/en/

---

Я хотел это и уточнить.Что нужно изменить или дописать или переписать вообще чтобы работало как я описал?
Есть ли у нас есть совпадение получается в условии,то мы просто выводим язык через document.write,а вот как дописать что если совпадения нет,то был редирект на английскую версию.

Comment: дак и где сам редирект?

Answer (score 0):

```
var lang = ['ru','en','pl','hu','de','sv','pt','no','tr','fi','be'];

var link = window.location.href;
var strArray = [];
var flag = true;

for (var i = 0; i < lang.length; i++) {
    lang[i] = '/' + lang[i] + '/';
    strArray[i] = link+lang[i];

    if(strArray[i] === window.location.href) {
        flag = false;
        link = strArray[1];
    } else {
        flag = true;
    }
}
console.log(flag);
```